# How to avoid getting empty emails from people pressing "Send" without actually filling up the form?

Tags: php, html

I have a form in my site and i getting a ton of empty mails from people i suppose only press send without actually filling up the form and is kinda annoying, my knowledge of PHP is extremely limited and i would love to know what do i need to change to stop receiving empty mails. The code of the form and the PHP is bellow.

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
<fieldset>
<legend>Contact us:</legend>
<input type="text" name="sender" placeholder="Name *">
<input type="text" name="senderEmail" placeholder="Email *">
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="5" cols="95"></textarea>
</fieldset>

<input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit" />
</form>
```

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="example@example.com";
    $subject="New email from form";
    $sender=$_POST["sender"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

    $thankYou="<p>Thanks! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}
```

Comment: Add both front and back validation. Front validations can be bypassed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a constraint on your textarea (front) :

```
 <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="5" cols="95" required></textarea>
```

You need to test the message content (back):

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $message = trim($_POST["message"]);
    if(!$message) {
       die("Empty message will not be sent");
    }

    $recipient="example@example.com";
    $subject="New email from form";
    $sender=$_POST["sender"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

    $thankYou="<p>Thanks! Your message has been sent.</p>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what i needed.